# Do UDK mutators only apply on local games?

Tags: udk

I have developed a pretty simple mutator. It works exactly as intended on a local game against bots, but it doesn't work (nor do any of the stock mutators) on a listen server.

Is this to be expected of UDK (May Beta Release by the way)?

Answer (score 1):

[The documentation](http://wiki.beyondunreal.com/UE3%3aMutator_%28UDK%29) certainly suggests they work for multiplayer games due to the number of references to "servers" and the like. It's possible your configuration is just such that mutators are disabled on your servers for some reason.

Comment: In pretty much every unreal engine version i've seen mutators have to be set on the server, and no other point of configuration matters.